# Importing ISAM table files (ISD, ISM) from one mysql to another

Tags: mysql, freebsd, myisam, isam

Problem: My db-host suddently switched my mysql db from one server to another. Unfortunately I has 1 table that was running ISAM, all other tables are MyISAM.
After the switch from one server to another the ISAM table is dead!

PHP sends "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" when trying to SELECT from the dead table.

In PHPMyAdmin a healthy tables has values for the columns accordingly 
(Records, Type, Collation)
885 MyISAM latin1_swedish_ci

The died table just has: "in use" writtin all over the three columns.

If i try to run view the structure of the table:

SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM  `table_name` ;

I get a: 
1017 - Can't find file: 'table_name' (errno: 2)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard someone say that ISAM files depends on operating system and mysql version where MyISAM files doesnt have that kind of dependencies? 
Actually I dont know if the file is corrupted or if its the switch to a new OS that killed the table.
I have tried with mysql 3.23, 4.01 and 5.1. Above 3.23 isamchk looks for a .MYD file, so im thinking that ISAM engine is out after this version. Using isamchk from 3.23 with -e (extend-check) or o- (safe-recover) the console app just dies after the "check delete-chain" command.

Would it be an idea to try running the isamchk on a mac or a linux or perhaps a freebsd (which the db came from)? Or are the implementations all the same?

Thanks